# Как в Pygame, называются клавиши Shift и Tab?

Tags: python, клавиатура, pygame

Как в Pygame, называется клавиша <kbd>shift</kbd> и клавиша <kbd>tab</kbd>?

Comment: [Тут ваш ответ](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)

Comment: if e.key == pygame.SHIFT:
                        hero.x = randint(100, 10000)
                        hero.y = randint(100, 10000)

Answer (score 1):

левый шифт - `K_LSHIFT` и правый - `K_RSHIFT`

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> — `K_TAB`,шифты - K_LSHIFT ,K_RSHIFT